# printing strings and inputs from file

Tags: awk

I have file named files.txt:

```
file1.F
data.dat
image.png
```

I would like to desired file including:

```
IN='file1.F'
IN='data.dat'
IN='image.png'
```

How to reach that? I tried this, but the syntax is poor:

```
awk '{print 'IN=\''$1'\''}' files.txt > input
```

Comment: Put `'` in a variable: `awk '{print "IN=" x $1 x}' x="'" file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -v s1="\047" -v var="IN=" '{print var s1 $0 s1}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
IN='file1.F'
IN='data.dat'
IN='image.png'
```

Answer (score 2):

If `sed` is an option.

```
sed "s/.*/IN='&'/" file
```

Output:

```
IN='file1.F'
IN='data.dat'
IN='image.png'
```